# Topology Questions

Tags: general-topology

So I am just wanting to make sure I had these right.  For the most part I think I have a solid understanding of both problems 1 and 2.  Both the last 2 problems, I think I understand them, but I am not 100% sure.

> **Problem 1:** Let $A= [0,8)$ be a subspace of $(\mathbb{R}, U)$. Which of the following sets are $U_A$-open? For each set $V$ that is $U_A$-open, find a $U$-open set $W$ for which $V = W \cap A$. Note: $U$ is the usual topology for $\mathbb{R}$.

(a) $[7,8)$ No.

(b) $(7,8)$ Yes, Let $W = (7,8)$.

(c) $[0,8)$ Yes, Let $W = (-2,10)$.

> **Problem 2:** Let $A= (0,8]$ be a subspace of $(\mathbb{R}, H)$. Which of the following sets are $H_A$-open? For each set $V$ that is $H_A$-open, find a $H$-open set W for which $V = W \cap A$. Note: $H$ is the topology for $\mathbb{R}$ which has a base $B$ of half open intervals $[a,b)$.

(a) $(0,1]$ No

(b) $[2,4]$ No

(c) $[2,4)$ Yes, Let $W= [2,4).

> **Problem 3:** Let $A= (-3,0] \cup [1,3)$ be a subspace of $(\mathbb{R}, C)$. Which of the following sets are $C_A$-open? For each set $V$ that is $C_A$-open, find a $C$-open set $W$ for which $V = W \cap A$. *Note*: $C$ is the topology for $\mathbb{R}$ where $C= \{ (a,\infty) : a ∈ \mathbb{R} \} \cup\{\mathbb{R},\varnothing\}$.

(a) $(-2,0] \cup [1,3)$ Yes, Let $W=(-2, \infty)$

(b) $(-2,0]\cup [2,3)$ No , the only $C$-open set would be $(-2, \infty)$ and this would not have $[2,3)$ in $V$.

(c) $(1,3)$ No, same as b more or less.

> **Problem 4:** Let X = {a,b,c,d} and τ = {X, Ø, {a}, {b,c}, {a,b,c}}. List the sets in each of the Following topologies:

(a) $\tau_{a,d} = \{\varnothing, \{a\}\}$.

(b) $\tau_{b,d} = \{\varnothing\}$.

(c.) $\tau_{a,b,c} = \{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$.

(d) $\tau_{d} = \{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: What does the notation for problem four mean? Also: if you got them all right I'm assuming you'd be find with a thumbs up; what sort of answer are you looking for if one is wrong?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by your question? and if one of them is wrong I'd like to know that its wrong and maybe a tip as to why without really telling me the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that what does $\tau E$ mean, where $E\subseteq X$? It's not a standard notation that I'm familiar with, and you didn't define it like $U,H,C$ (which are also not standard, so thanks for that!).

Comment: Oh its just T for topology.  It was just a script T that I saw and decided to use.

Comment: I'm not seeing an E?

Comment: You wrote $\tau\{b,d\}$, for example. What is $\{b,d\}$ doing?

Comment: Ahhhh gotcha so in the book they are subscripts.  To what they represent I am not 100% sure.  I think its the relative topology for {b,d}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems $1$ and $2$ are perfect.

Your answer to $3($c$)$ is not correct; the situation is not the same as in part (b). You might want to look at part (b) more carefully, though. Your answer is correct but I'm not sure about your reasoning, since $[2,3)$ is a subset of $(-2,\infty)\cap A$.

For Problem $4$, the image you link (and the notation in the rest of the question) suggests that $\tau_A$ is the topology $\tau$ restricted to the set $A$. In particular, it cannot be that any set in $\tau_A$ contains any point not in $A$, so none of them should contain $X$. There are some other mistakes which I'll leave to you to figure out now that you understand the problem statement.

Comment: @Quickie37: Also, I edited your question to use LaTeX formatting. If you're learning topology then you probably are pretty serious about mathematics; you should eventually learn how to use it :) If you edit your question, you can see how I did it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am suppose to edit my original post or not. So basically my reasoning for 3(b) is that when you find (−2,∞)∩A they do have 2 in the resulting set which means you could have a closed interval [2,3).  For part d I am still not seeing anything that would lead me to saying yes.  How can you get an intersetion when A doesn't include 1.

Comment: It's not unusual to edit the original post, especially for  the original poster, so don't worry about it. Also, $A$ does include 1; it's the open set that you don't want to contain 1. Can you see why that's not a big deal? (what is an analogous situation in $U$?)

Comment: Oh so 4 would just be let W= (1,+∞)?

Also here is a picture of the only example in my book that pertains to number 4 and the only thing I have to go off of.
http://i.imgur.com/gaWNdSy.png

Comment: Yep :) That works.

Comment: @Quickie37: I just saw your image and it made me understand, so I updated my answer.

Comment: I edited my answers to the 4th Problem.  I think they are right.  From my understanding of your explanation, any set in $\tau_A$ cannot contain a point that is not in A so for example if you had A={1,2,3,4}.  You couldn't have {1,2,3,4,5} in the set right?

Comment: That's a good start, but each of the $\tau_E$ have to be topologies as well.